# Merge the "lastfm" and "last.fm" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I wanted to suggest a tag merge for [lastfm](/questions/tagged/lastfm) (62 questions) and [last.fm](/questions/tagged/last.fm) (38 questions).

For what it is worth, I would keep [last.fm](/questions/tagged/last.fm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed.  I've merged the [lastfm](/questions/tagged/lastfm) tag into the [last.fm](/questions/tagged/last.fm) tag and a synonym has been created.